# How to create dropdown menu from python list using Flask and HTML

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu in HTML using info from a python script. I've gotten it to work thus far, however, the html dropdown displays all 4 values in the lists as 4 options.

Current: **Option 1:** Red, Blue, Black Orange; **Option 2:** Red, Blue, Black, Orange etc. (Screenshot in link)
[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w0tz.png)

Desired: **Option 1:** Red
**Option 2:** Blue
etc.

How do I make it so that the python list is separated?

dropdown.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def dropdown():
    colours = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Black', 'Orange']
    return render_template('test.html', colours=colours)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dropdown</title>
</head>
<body>
<select name= colours method="GET" action="/">
    {% for colour in colours %}
    <option value= "{{colour}}" SELECTED>{{colours}}</option>"
    {% endfor %}
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you have a typo, replace `colours` to `colour`

```
<option value= "{{colour}}" SELECTED>{{colours}}</option>"
```

replace to

```
<option value= "{{colour}}" SELECTED>{{ colour }}</option>"
                                     <!--  ^^^^ -->
```

Answer (score 31):

You need to use `{{colour}}` in both places (instead of `{{colours}}` in the second place):

```
<select name="colour" method="GET" action="/">
    {% for colour in colours %}
        <option value="{{colour}}" SELECTED>{{colour}}</option>"
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Note that using `selected` inside the loop will add `selected` attribute to all options and the last one will be selected, what you need  to do is the following:

```
<select name="colour" method="GET" action="/">
  <option value="{{colours[0]}}" selected>{{colours[0]}}</option>
  {% for colour in colours[1:] %}
    <option value="{{colour}}">{{colour}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```