# Flask - get value from dropdown button

Tags: python, flask

im trying to get a value from a button that is inside of a form like so:

```
    <form class="search-form" method="post" action="">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle text-primary" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" name="platform" value="platform">
                Choose Platform
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li>Steam</li>
                <li>PSN</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
```

With a JS i change the text inside the Button

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
```

Inside of the FlaskApp -> When i try to get the Button's Value from the Form with `platform = request.form['platform']` im getting `KeyError: 'platform'`

Comment: Not really a flask problem, form data only includes the clicked submit button. Try changing it to`type="submit"`.

Comment: with `type=submit` i also get the same error

Comment: why not provide with full example?

Comment: full code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73983956/flask-html-js-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-in-combination-with-flask)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fetch the data from the button element but had no success.

My guess is that Flask/Werkzeug does not capture button's data. I went through the documentation and the debugger but did not find why exactly this is happening.

You can add a hidden field and assign the value to it instead.

Comment: After trying it with an hidden input i can get the value of the input but sadly not what i choosed in the Button dropdown.

Comment: Show me the code where you added the value to the hidden input field

Comment: `$(".search-button").click(function(){
        var elem = document.getElementById('submit');
        var txt = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
        document.getElemenrById('hidden_input').value = txt;
    });`

Comment: you have a typo in `document.getElemenrById('hidden_input').value `  should be `document.getElementById('hidden_input').value`

Comment: oh yep, i reconstructed what i did to that time sorry for that, sadly it wont work with or without the typo ;)

Comment: so, i finally found an solution that is working for me, it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877080/how-to-create-dropdown-menu-from-python-list-using-flask-and-html)